# ASP.NET MVC: code:-32000 message: No script for id: 32

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio, ssl, model-view-controller

I'll try and give as much detail as I can because the error message is not very helpful. Basically when I try and run my web application in Visual Studio, I get this in the Debug output:

```
code:-32000
message:No script for id: 32
```

Those are the only two lines that are displayed.
When those lines show, my entire application stops launching and the "Process Memory" in the Visual Studio diagnostic tools stays flat at a constant 13MB (sits around 250MB when launched properly).
I am completely stumped as to what is going on; everything was working fine yesterday afternoon, and I haven't done anything since then. I have updated anything that can be updated, restarted Visual Studio and my computer multiple times, and re-cloned the entire repository to a completely separate directory. Nothing I have tried has worked.
Information online about these two error codes have vastly different solutions from thread-to-thread. Some have nothing to do with what I am doing, while others have not worked. The closest thread I have found relating to my issue is here: [Visual Studio Link](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/78159/debug-code-code-32000-messageno-script-for-id-32.html). The only reason I say it's related is because the last thing I did was setup SSL for secure connections on the production and test sites.
It is worth mentioning that the production and test sites still work completely fine when running on the servers and I can connect to/load them as normal. However, if I try running my development branch on my local machine, that is when the issue occurs. I have even tried cloning the test and production branches to my local machine and running them; I still get the same issue.
I am waiting for a colleague to get in, and I am going to try launching it on his computer to see if it is a problem unique to my machine. I will edit this post when I have done that.

If anyone has any ideas as to what might be happening, I'd be glad to read it. If not, I guess I'll just have to wait for this Visual Studio fix from the page I linked earlier, or find some other workaround.
Here's a screenshot of the debug window: [Debug Window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MS95E.png)

Edit: To address the potential duplicate question. I believe my issue is SSL related, which has nothing to do with the referenced question. Also, the solution to the referenced question was just to upgrade Visual Studio, but I am running on a fully up-do-date version.

Comment: @LeandroTaset Doesn't seem likely as I am running a more recent version than the version which fixed the issue for OP in the link you posted.

Answer (score 2):

A simple work-around is to disable the IE and Chrome script debugger if you prefer to use Chrome's own dev tools to do client-side debugging.

In Tools -> Options -> Debugging -> General
[image]

Answer (score 0):

There have been a number of updates to VS 2017 the last couple of days. Have you checked that you've got the latest applied, maybe this was introduced and fixed recently - which is kind of suggested by the VS link you have included?

Comment: I have fully updated Visual Studio. The latest release version is 15.2 (26430.16), which is what I have installed. The version shown in the page I linked is 15.3. I could try and find a pre-release version and see if that solves my issue, but I would rather not do that if I could avoid it.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so after my colleague came in and we tried running the site on his computer, it also did not initially work. After we troubleshooted many different options, we seem to have found a solution (if you can call this a solution).

So the issue did originate from the fact that I had just implemented the SSL certificates and automatic redirection links so the users are always using https.
When I debug in Visual Studio, I use Google Chrome as my default browser. Here is where my speculation begins. Due to the fact that I am running a development version of the site on my local machine, the SSL certificates (or something related to SSL) becomes invalid/not authenticated. Also, for whatever reason, Chrome was automatically redirecting my localhost links from http to https even though I only apply the redirection property through the transform files (in other words, the dev build does not get the redirection property). In short Chrome was forcing me to try and access my localhost through https (I don't now why or how it knew to try and automatically redirect to https). I switched the default browser to debug with from Google Chrome to Microsoft Edge, and the website launched and loaded on the localhost perfectly (with http as it should have for localhost).

TLDR: Swapped the default browser to debug with from Google Chrome to Microsoft Edge. This fixed some sort of automatic https redirection from Chrome that was breaking the site when launching through Visual Studio.